# How to add news Ticker on home page only

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed a news ticker plugin,

Then I added necessary function/code in sidebar.php

```
<!-- BEGIN: #secondary -->
<div id="secondary" class="g1-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
<h3>Latest News</h3>
<div id="news">
<?php if ( function_exists('insert_newsticker') ) { insert_newsticker(); } ?>
</div>
.......
.........
</div>
```

Now news ticker coming on all page's sidebar.

But i want it to add in only home page sideabr.

Is there any way to do this, so if side bar is primary/home

then only display news ticker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `is_front_page()` for the front page check.

```
if( is_front_page() && function_exists('insert_newsticker') ){
    insert_newsticker();
}
```

More Information [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

#### Updated according to Comments:

```
<div id="secondary" class="g1-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
<?php if( is_front_page() ): ?>
// Your h3 tag here
<?php endif; ?>
<h3>Latest News</h3>
<div id="news">
```

Comment: thanks working fine, just one more things, how can I add one more <h3> tag dynamically in sidebar if page is home page

Comment: @PK10 Please check the updated code, and hope you want like this.

Comment: yeah exactly u got it but I getting news title "Latest News" on every page and want it on home page only

Answer (score 0):

use 'is_home' function more detail: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Comment: `is_home()` actually checks for blog index page, which is NOT the static home page

Answer (score 0):

The $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI]  will contain the uri of the current address so if you compare that to the homepage ("/") it will allow you to see whether to insert it. You could also fairly easily add support for other pages on your site if you decided to add the plugin there at a later date.